# How can I set JsonSerializerSettings for Akavache?

Tags: json, akavache

I have set the global converter defaults for JSON.NET like so:

```
        var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new QuestionTypeConverter() }
        };
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => jsonSerializerSettings;
```

This works well with the rest of my code ("QuestionTypeConverter" is being used and works as expected), however, when retrieving an object from the Akavache cache, my "QuestionTypeConverter" is ignored and thus my object does not get deserialized properly.
How can I enforce the usage of my custom type converters with Akavache or have Akavache use the default settings of JSON.NET?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(mySettings, typeof(JsonSerializerSettings))` to override the serializer settings for Akavache

Comment: Is it Newtonsoft's or System.Text.Json?